# What is {...props} in react navigation Stack.Screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

What is the significance of `{...props}` on [this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#passing-additional-props)?

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

Without `{...props}` also, my app runs fine.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this mdn page for [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docs description:

> Sometimes we might want to pass additional props to a screen.

For passing additional props it uses a renderer (render callback) function. actually, it is additional and obviously your codes should word without it.

The formal usage is like below:

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{ title: 'Overview' }}
/>
```

Als, in the formal usage `React Navigation`, applies optimizations to screen components to prevent unnecessary renders. I offer you to use this style, but if you need the additional props that the `Stack.Screen` would pass to the render component, use the renderer version **but note** using a renderer removes whole given optimizations by `React Navigation`.

If you wanna know what is the additional props, use the renderer version and then use `console.log` it in `HomeScreen` component:

```js
const HomeScreen = props => {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```